# numpy.loadtxt unix timestamp converter

Tags: python, datetime, numpy

I have a large file consisting of OHLC stock values and volume. Each row starts with an unix timestamp. How can I convert it to a datetime object which numpy will understand. Here is my code:

```
entry_timestamp, entry_close, entry_high, entry_low, entry_open, entry_volume = \
    np.loadtxt(filename, delimiter = ',', unpack = True,
               converters = { 0 : lambda data: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(data))})
```

And here is a sample row of the data which I try to load into the arrays:

> `1441197159,75.54,100`

*1441197159* is the unix timestamp. I know how to manually convert it into a datetime object but how to pass it to the np.loadtxt as a converter? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your converter is working just fine, actually. The problem is that the output of the converter must match the `dtype` of the output array, which by default is `float64`. So you're creating an array of `datetime`s, then trying to save that into a `float` array.

Either you must make the change after running `loadtxt`, or use a structured dtype like so:

```
import numpy as np
from datetime.datetime import fromtimestamp

filename = 'tmp.txt'

entry_timestamp, entry_close, entry_high, entry_low, entry_open, entry_volume = \
    np.loadtxt(filename, dtype='O,'+'f8,'*5, delimiter=',', unpack=True,
               converters={0: lambda d: fromtimestamp(float(d))})
```

where the `'O'` stands for `np.dtype('O')`, or `dtype=object`. The `'f8'`, of course, means `np.dtype('float64')`. All together, this gives you the structured dtype with 6 types:

```
>>> np.dtype('O,'+'f8,'*5)
dtype([('f0', 'O'), ('f1', '<f8'), ('f2', '<f8'), ('f3', '<f8'), ('f4', '<f8'), ('f5', '<f8')])
```

But once you split it up with `unpack=True`, you'll just have a single array with each type.